# How to handle environmental variables on production on a React Project on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, heroku, environment-variables

I have my Heroku connected to Github and my react project has a .env file with my Firebase config.

I don't upload the .env to github for security reasons.

But then, it doesn't get uploaded to Heroku and my project doesn't work. Or should it work anyway? Without the .env it doesn't have access to the config like the apikey.

So should I upload the .env file to Heroku? Is that safe?

How am I supossed to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set environment variables on Heroku, see:

[image: Environment Variables on Heroku]

---

Reactjs is typically a client side framework. You are usually not doing SSR. Are you certain you are doing SSR? Because if are serving the static html,js,css files people already have access to your firebase config by looking at the browser source.

Comment: Looks like that is what I was looking for. I'll try it. I'm not 100% sure of what you mean on the last paragraph. I'm using firebase as a database and also the authentication service. The config info is all in a .env file. You mean everyone can see that anyway? There is no way to hide it?

Comment: It depends if your website works based on client side rendering or not. If it is client side rendering your users will have access to your credentials. Reactjs is typically a client side framework. If you are doing server side rendering then it's hidden.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's front side rendering. Then my credentials are exposed, that's a huge issue.